# why animation doesn't work in QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I want to set my fullscreen app on one of my screens, so I have to set its height,width, x,y and so on.  However I found the animation doesn't work.

I ever thought this caused by I set it on one targeted screen, so I create a test code, here I hard code the x,y, but the animation still doesn't work, can someone tell me why?

My test code is as following:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    flags: Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.FramelessWindowHint
    opacity: 0.6
    id: root

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            //Qt.quit();
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        root.x = 0;
        root.y = 0;
        root.width = Screen.width;
        root.height = Screen.height;
        initWindow.start();
    }

    PropertyAnimation {
        id: initWindow
        target: root
        from: 0
        to: Screen.height
        duration: 2000
        easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
        onRunningChanged: {
            if(!initWindow.running && root.visibility != Window.Hidden){
                console.log("here is initWindow animation.")
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: You code is good but you forget to set a property you want to animate.

Answer (score 1):

Because you do not animate anything.
You need to specify a target.

Just a wild guess, but you probably want to animate the height?

```
Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    //        opacity: 0.6 // Does not work for me
    // I want to have the frames and stuff for an example.

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            //Qt.quit();
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        root.x = 0;
        root.y = 0;
        root.width = 1200;
        root.height = 800;
    }

    Behavior on height { // Starts the Animation with the set target, once the height is set to be changed
        NumberAnimation {
            id: initWindow
            duration: 200000
        }
    }
}
```

Or to stay closer to your code:

```
Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            Qt.quit();
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        root.x = 0;
        root.y = 0;
        root.width = Screen.width;
        initWindow.start();
    }

    PropertyAnimation {
        id: initWindow
        target: root
        from: 0
        to: Screen.height
        property: 'height' // You need to declare which property should change.
        duration: 2000
        easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
    }
}
```

See the comments, for what I did.
And I striped your code of some stuff unnecessary for an example.